# Scroll Xamarin Forms listview when using bindings

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am brand new to Xamarin and MVVM so this may be a stupid question.

I have a ListView which is populated using an observable collection, that collection is added to by a viewmodel.

What i want to do is when an item is added I want to scroll the listview to the bottom however the viewmodel does not have visibility to the listview control.

How can i get my listview to scroll when a new item is added to its collection?

Comment: Probably the cleanest thing to do is roll your own, or find a package that has this kind of functionality. But as far as I know, there isn't one. You could easily create a inheritance of the `ListView`, check if an item is coming in and scroll it into view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use MessagingCenter.

In your ViewModel, when you Add the new Item you can MessagingCenter.Send a message, and in your Page you can subscribe to this message. When you receive this message in your Page, you can ScrollTo your ListView